# Prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}$ uniformly converges on $[-1,1].$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}$ uniformly converges on $[-1,1].$

My book says I have use alternating series test. I can see that the series converges for any $x\in[-1,1]$ by the alternating series test but it doesn't tell us the series is *uniformly convergent* on $[-1,1]$. I tried to use Weierstrass M-Test instead but it fails to pass the M-test.

I let $f_k(x) = \dfrac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}$ and found $M_k = \sup\{|\dfrac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}|:x\in[-1,1]\} = \dfrac{1}{2k+1}$. But $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2k+1}$ is not convergent and does not pass the M-test. Hence, the series cannot be uniformly convergent.

Did I use the M-Test correctly?

Comment: @πr8 Oops, I thought $x^k$, not $x^{2k+1}$ ...

Comment: The Weierstrass $M$-test isn't a “test” in the way that the Ratio or Root Test is.  You can't use it to conclude that a power series does not converge uniformly.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Then what would be the purpose of using the M-test then? I am really confused because I've been using it to test convergence for series problems. Are you saying if M-test fails, I can't conclude anything about the series?

Comment: By "if the $M$-test fails", I guess you are referring to the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sup\left\{\left|\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\right| : x \in [-1,1]\right\}$ does not converge.  That's not a failure of the test; rather, the test *does not apply.*  It just means you have to use another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $x\in[0,1]$, the sequence $\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$ is monotone decreasing (and for $x\in[-1,0]$, the negative of this sequence is monotone decreasing).

If $a_k$ is a monotone decreasing, nonnegative sequence, the alternating series test says that:

1. $\sum_{k \ge 1} (-1)^k a_k$ converges to some $s$
2. $|s - \sum_{1 \le k \le n}(-1)^k a_k|<a_{n+1}$

Thus, if $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} x^{2k+1}$ and $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} x^{2k+1}$, then $$|f(x)-f_n(x)|\le \frac{ |x|^{2n+3} }{2n+3}\le \frac{1}{2n+3} \to 0$$

Comment: But if we use the alternating series test, don't we only know that the series is convergent not *uniformly convergent*?

Comment: You have a uniform bound on $|f(x)-f_n(x)|$; this is what is needed for uniform convergence.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not sure what you mean by uniform bound. Don't we need to make sure that $\| f(x)-f_n(x) \|_{\sup} < \epsilon$?

Comment: Is $\dfrac{1}{2n+3}$ from your last inequality $\|f(x)-f_n(x)\|_{\sup}$? It seems to me that it is and therefore the series is uniformly convergent.

Comment: A uniform bound is the same as a supremum bound, yes. $\| f(x)-f_n(x) \|_{\sup} = \sup_{x\in [-1,1]} |f(x)-f_n(x)|$. Since $|f(x)-f_n(x)|<\frac{1}{2n+3}$ for all relevant $x$, it is clear that $\sup_{x\in [-1,1]} |f(x)-f_n(x)|<\frac{1}{2n+3}$ also. So yes, the series certainly is uniformly convergent.

Comment: Is there some condition for a series such that passing the alternating series test will imply uniformly convergent? As in this example, the series is convergent for closed and bounded radius. Does the uniform convergence depend on the radius of convergence being closed or open?

Comment: I just realized there is a theorem for power series, that the power series must be uniformly convergent for the closed interval of radius of convergence. If I were to use this theorem, can't I have just showed that the series passes the alternating series test for $x\in[-1,1]$ and therefore convergent?

Comment: Maybe - one could conceivably adapt the proof above to prove a result of this form for power series with decaying coefficients of alternating sign.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} x^{2k+1},$$ and call $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} x^{2k+1}.$$

Note that $$f_n'(s)=-s^2\frac{1-(-s^2)^n}{1+s^2} \implies f(x)=- \int_0^x s^2\frac{1-(-s^2)^n}{1+s^2}\,ds$$ and $$f(x)=\arctan(x)-x=-\int_0^x\frac{s^2}{1+s^2}\,ds.$$

Thus:

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\left| \int_0^x \frac{s^{2(n+1)}}{1+s^2}\,ds\right| \le \left| \int_0^1 s^{2(n+1)}\,ds\right|=\frac{1}{2n+3}\to0$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont' quite understand your answer. How can you take derivative of $f_n(x)$? And what is the variable $s$? Is it just an arbitrary element from $[-1,1]$? I feel frustrated because I don't know how am I supposed to come up with such crazy proof... if that's the only way to solve this. Can you comment on my attempt of using M-test? I think I used it properly but the series fails the M-test.

Comment: 1) You can take the derivative of $f_n$ by differentiating it term-by-term; $f_n$ is just a polynomial. 2) Yes, $s$ is just a dummy variable. 3) To show uniform convergence, you need to control the difference between the partial sums ($f_n$ in this question) and the true limit ($f$), and integrals often end up being a good way of doing so. 4) The M-test doesn't work here because, as you say, the terms in the resulting sum do not have a convergent sum.